# Running a process at startup and viewing its console output via ssh (or other means)

Tags: gnu-screen, headless

Is there a way I can have a process on a headless server which runs at startup, and still be able to connect remotely at a later time to view the console input? I need to be able to view console output via ssh or some other means.

Simply redirecting output to a file won't work because these processes never exit and constantly output lines. If I just redirect to a file it'll fill up the disk... (I only really care about the last 20 lines or so.)

I don't think "screen" is an option since I need run at boot time without interaction.

Comment: This doesnt exactly answer your question, but you could write the output to a file instead of stdout.

Comment: Yes I have considered that (see 2nd part above), but unless there's some way to limit the file size, that will get big fast. I suppose I could have some process to delete it periodically but not sure what the best method would be. Dunno if deleting the file at the same time the process tries to write to it would be "bad". But that would work if these issues can be worked around.

Comment: You have to store the output to a file no matter what anyway... If you expect the operating system to report to you the output of processes that run on startup, then you MUST store the output in some log file. whether you write the functionality yourself or have a process manager (or systemctl for example) log stdout. Either way, it gets logged to a file.

Comment: also to extend on what I just posted, you should also implement verbose logging (write additional information to stdout). That way your log files don't get extremely large over time when deploying your applications for production.

Comment: This isn't an application I've written so I have no control over the volume of logging. Guessing from lack of replies I guess it's just not possible to do it like a terminal session. It would be nice to have a way to ensure what goes to disk gets purged at some point, though.

Comment: well its not entirely impossible. you could make another executable in C/C++. All you have to do is use exec to run the command you want, then read from the child processes stdout. from there, log the output to a file. Then you can use systemctl to start the executable on boot.

Comment: this is an extremely common practice btw ^^^^ fork + exec is your best friend here

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use screen for this purpose. You will just need to add a cron job for it:

```bsh
crontab -e
# Add line to the end, like:
# @reboot /usr/bin/screen -dm <command/script (remember to make sure it is using the right directories/permissions)>
```